# Spring Boot + Security configuration for communication with Angular app

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the spring boot application running on the domain A.It purpose is to expose some REST endpoints.

Also, I have angular 8 application. It could be deployed on the same domain A, or in other domain B.
The spring boot app is aware of on which domain is angular app deployed.

I need to configure Spring security,so it will accept requests on particular endpoints ONLY from the angular app. But also, some of the endpoints need to be role-aware

For example:

- /api/v1/resources/** - should be from angular app only
- /api/v1/resources/admin/** - should be only from angular app AND user should have admin role
- /api/v1/payments/** - this can accept requests not only from angular app (merchant callbacks for example)

I would highly appreciate some pieces of advice on the best approach for this

Comment: Protecting the backend by application authorization is not that easy and almost impossible. Mainly because is a webapp that is calling the your backend. Anyone can debug your app using the browser (since the code is in Javascript (client-side)) and create a client to your backend APIs using your Angular App credentials. That's why, for front-end, I always prefer user authentication over application authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by applying URL specific filter in securityConfig.java class where you have extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class also you need to pass one custom header from your Angular app.

```
@Autowired
private HeaderFilter headerFilter;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/api/v1/resources/**")
        .addFilterBefore(headerFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

You can create HeaderFilter.class and inside doFilter() method implement like below.

```
public class HeaderFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();

        if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                request.getHeader("YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER");
                //get Angular app specific header and it's value whether it is correct then true else stop filter chain.
                if(FOUND){
                   chain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                   throw Exception();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can also add ROLE BASED additional authentication for ADMIN access in securityconfig.java

Answer (score 0):

In your WebSecurityConfig class which extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (`org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) edit your  configure mwthod as this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/resources/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/payments/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()           
            ...
            ...
        }
```

Comment: This won't work, because this provide solution based on USER role not based on platform from which API gets called.